# CodenameOne build fails reporting SSLHandShakeException

Tags: windows, netbeans, codenameone, java-11

I am following CodenameOne Hello World Tutorial.
My setup is Windows 10, Oracle JDK 11 and Netbeans 12.2.
I have registered in CodenameOne to get an account. I can run the app in simulator, however when I send a an Android or Windows UWP build to cloud I get a SSL Handshake Exception.

I have reinstalled Netbeans and CodenameOne but the issue still persists. I noticed this line in the trace:

```
Sending build to account: null
```

I can login successfully from CodenameOne plugin but account value is always null.

Trace log below.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

```
build-for-windows-device:
Your build size is: 2kb
Sending build request to the server, notice that the build might take a while to complete!
Sending build to account: null
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1356)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1323)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1321)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:793)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1320)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:241)
    at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendS3Build(BuildProcess.java:460)
    at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendRequestToServer(BuildProcess.java:491)
    at com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask.execute(CodeNameOneBuildTask.java:550)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:574)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:123)
C:\Projects\NetBeans\CN1\CodenameOne\build.xml:617: Error in server build process
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running Netbeans with Java11, seems that CodenameOne works with Java 8.
I changed the netbeans_jdkhome variable from netbeans.conf file to jdk8 and now works fine.
Problem solved.

Comment: Codename One works with Java 11. Make sure your plugin is up to date and update your project libs via Codename One Settings -> Basic -> Update Project Libs. Otherwise bad things can happen like builds not showing up etc...

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately I tried your tip but does not work for me. If I launch netbeans12.2 with Java11 I always got the SSL Handshake exception sending build to cloud. However if I launch netbeans12.2 with Java8 cloud build works fine.  I am referring to the JVM version that is used to launch Netbeans and not the one set in Netbeans project (from Project.>Properties->Libraries), this one works fine if I set it to Java 11.

Comment: So am I. That is odd. Which specific version of JDK 11 are you using and from what vendor? This means our certificate isn't recognized by the JDK which doesn't make sense as this is an Amazon certificate in this stage and a cloudflare certificate later on. Both are from well known authorities.

Comment: C:\Java>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)

Comment: IMPLEMENTOR="Oracle Corporation"

Comment: I installed official Oracle Java 11.09 and wiith this version works fine.

C:\Users\jrovira>java -version
java version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9+7-LTS, mixed mode)

Comment: I think your earlier JDK 11was relatively old and might have been missing some root certificates needed to connect to our webservices. Since root certificates get revoked/replaced frequently this is somewhat unavoidable.